# In a normed vector space,open connected set is path-connected.(Proof using equivalence relation)

Tags: algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, alternative-proof, connectedness, path-connected

Suppose $(V,\Vert.\Vert)$ is a normed linear space(NLS) and $E$ is an open connected set in $V$,show that $E$ is pathwise connected.

Proof:

**Definition**:A subset $E$ of a normed linear space $V$ is said to be polygonally connected if for each $x,y\in E$,$\exists x=x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n=y$ in $E$ such that $\{tx_{k-1}+(1-t)x_k : t\in [0,1]\}\subset E$
 .

In this problem,it suffices to show that $E$ is polygonally connected.Define an equivalence relation on $E$ as follows:

$x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have a polygonal connection in $E$.

Verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $E$.

So,$\sim$ generates a quotient set $E/\sim$ ,the set of all equivalence classes of $E$ by $\sim$.

Now we shall show that $E/\sim$ is a singleton and contains $E$ only.

Let,$x\in E$,then $[x]\in E/\sim$

We shall show below that $[x]$ is closed in $E$.

For that we take a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $[x]$ which converges to $x_0\in E$.We will show that $x_0\in [x]$.

Since $x_0\in E$ and $E$ is open,so $\exists r>0$ such that $B(x_0,r)\subset E$. 
Note that $B(x_0,r)$ is open in $E$.

Now $(x_n)\to x_0$,hence $x_n\in B(x_0,r)$ eventually($\forall n\geq N$ ,say).

Now $V$ is a normed linear space,so $B(x_0,r)$ is convex ,so for an $n\geq N$,$x_n$ and $x_0$ are connected polygonally and hence $x_n\sim x_0$ but $x_n\in [x]$.So,$x_0\in [x]$.

Thus $[x]$ is closed in $E$.

Now we show that $[x]$ is open in $E$.

We shall take a sequence $(a_n)\subset E$ converging to a point $a$ of $[x]$ and show that $a_n\in[x]$ eventually.

since $a\in [x]\subset E$ and $E$ is open,so $B(a,r)\subset E$ for some $r>0$.

Clearly any point of $B(a,r)$ is polygonally connected to $a$ as balls are convex in NLS $V$.

and also $a\in [x]$,so $B(a,r)\subset [x]$.Now $(a_n)\to a$ and hence eventually $(a_n)$ is in $B(a,r)$ and hence $a_n \in [x]$ eventually.

So,$[x]$ is open in $E$.

So,$[x]$ is a non-empty closed-open set in $E$ and $E$ is connected.So,$[x]=E$ and we are done.

So,any two points in $E$ have a polygonal connection between them.So,$E$ is polygonally connected and is obviously path connected.

Is there anything wrong in this proof?Can anyone suggest any alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Here is a shorter proof.

Clearly each path component $P$ of an open subset $E \subset V$ is open in $V$ because if $x \in P$ and $B(x,r) \subset E$, then $B(x,r) \subset P$. Thus the path components of $E$ form a partition of $E$ into pairwise disjoint open subsets.

If $E$ is connected and has more than one path compenent, we get a non-trivial partition into pairwise disjoint open subsets which is a contradiction.